# Exporting Single Frame Animations to .FBX not working. (Blender v2.76b, Bin-Exporter v7.4)

Tags: animation

I'm trying to export single frame animations to the .FBX format which doesn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to create multiple single-key animations using the action editor in Dope Sheet and export them to .FBX so I can use them in the Unreal Engine 4. The exported .fbx file has the mesh and armature (skeleton) but no animations, as if they where not exported. I checked this not only by trying to import them to the UE4, but also by checking the file in Autodesk's FBX Converter tool.

The only way I can get the animations to appear is if I toggle the "All Actions" and the "Add Keyframe to beginning and End of animation settings". This results in animations getting exported, but they then consist of 2 keyframes which is unwanted.

So my question is, how do I get single key animations into an FBX file.

Thanks for any help,

I'm using Blender v2.76b and the Binary FBX Exporter v7.4 (also tried the ASCII version, same result)

Comment: The question is unclear, to me: you either say "single frame animations" (which make no sense to me) or "single-key animations" (which I don't know about, really, and I never used UE4). Maybe attach an example .blend that you wish to export to fbx, and/or some screenshot to better understand.

Comment: I'm talking about single (1) key-frame animations. Which seem unable to be exportable. No animation shows up in the blend file. But I guess it doesn't matter, I've implemented a workaround in the unreal engine, I just remove the other frame manually.

Comment: I've just come across this problem myself. Frustratingly, the only way I can get around it is by ticking bake_anim_use_all_bones and bake_anim_force_startend_keying, which increases the size of the fbx 10 fold. For some reason the exporter ignores single frame actions, this seems more like a bug than common sense if you ask me.